# Pick value only after change ngx-currency

Tags: angular

I want pick the value only after change the input value, I need to make a sum after typing the value.

```
<input currencyMask [(ngModel)]="baixa.juros" (ngModelChange)="setJuros($event.target.value)" [options]="{ prefix: '', thousands: '.', decimal: ',', allowNegative: false }" name="valor_juros" id="valor_juros_liq" class="input-default" />
```

It does not work because it calls the function with each keyup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `(focusout)` instead to call the function only when you are done with input value.

The `(change)` method triggers each time the value is changed, and that's with each key press also.

Comment: <input currencyMask [(ngModel)]="baixa.juros" (focusout)="setJuros()" [options]="{ prefix: '', thousands: '.', decimal: ',', allowNegative: false }" name="valor_juros" id="valor_juros_liq" class="input-default" />